# regarding self in method calls python, couldnt get a specific answer to my query

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
class downloader(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
```

---

Can someone explain why there is a self in the method call? was self to be used only for method definitions and not mandatory for method calls?

Comment: Can you please consult the [documentation on classes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes) first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `x.foo()`, then `self` is added as the first argument only if `x` is an instance of a class (making `foo` a bound function). However, if `x` is itself a class, the function is unbounded and no parameter will be added.

In your case, `QDialog` is a class, so it does not add `self` automatically, thus the need to add it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Instance methods always receive an implicit first argument. You can call it whatever you want, but usually the word "self" is used (just like the word "this" is used in similar contexts of other languages)